# How to add subscript and superscript in WordPress page titles

Tags: title

It is possible to add subscript and superscript in a WordPress page title? I need to add pages with "H<sub>2</sub>O" in the title.

I have been searching, but cannot find anything with answers... only a few non-answered threads on wordpress.org forums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use markup in titles. `H<sub>2</sub>O` will work just fine. I would use H₂O with a real `₂` because markup will be stripped in title attributes and in feeds.

Note that WordPress will not create a pretty permalink for the correct character. The slug for my example will look like this: `h2o-h%e2%82%82o`.
You need my plugin [Germanix URL](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) to get `h2o` for both variants.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had a DOH! moment. I was using a page template that didn't actually show the title and I thought `<sub> </sub>` was creating an error and displaying nothing...

Comment: ...and thanks for the tip about HTML special characters. Definitely the way to go.

Comment: @TravisPflanz See my update with a note about the permalink problem.

Comment: My permalink did not do that. It is displayed as `H<sub>2</sub>O`. I did, however, add `H2O` to the "Redirection".

Comment: I just realized the subscript didn't show in my comment - My permalink did not do that. It is displayed as H2O with the 2 subscript. I did, however, add `H2O` to the "Redirection" plugin to point to H(subscript 2)O. This should work correctly, right?

Comment: I have no experience with that plugin.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was referring more to general URL and redirection principles. The plugin redirects as intended.